# Countdown.js reset time

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, count, countdown

Hello I try to start and reset the counter from countdown.js with pressing one button.

When I press the button a second time it starts a new timer and jump between the old timer and new one.

I would like to clear the timer / reset the timer and start then.

I tried using clearInterval(timeinterval); as a single button and it's not working either.

```
$("#reset").click(function () {
    //timer = new Countdown();
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
});
```

```js
    
$("#trigger-start").click(function () {

    var check = true;

    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 20 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

    $(".button-content-start").toggleClass("stop");
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock row m-b-xl">
<div id="clockdiv">
    <div class="panel-solid-info widget-mini col-xs-3" id="canvas_days" style="padding:0 1px !important;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="total text-center val days"><span id="countdown-tage"></span></span>
            <span class="title text-center type-days type-time">Tage</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-solid-info widget-mini col-xs-3" id="canvas_hours" style="padding:0 1px !important;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="total text-center val hours"><span id="countdown-stunden"></span></span>
            <span class="title text-center type-hours type-time">Stunden</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-solid-info widget-mini col-xs-3" id="canvas_minutes" style="padding:0 1px !important;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="total text-center val minutes"><span id="countdown-minuten"></span></span>
            <span class="title text-center type-minutes type-time">Minuten</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-solid-info widget-mini col-xs-3" id="canvas_minutes" style="padding:0 1px !important;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="total text-center val seconds"><span id="countdown-sekunden"></span></span>
            <span class="title text-center type-seconds type-time">Sekunden</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal"
    id="trigger-start"><i class="button-content-start">Start</i></button>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please make sure to format your code samples when you post so they are easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that setInterval continued executed the function. In the next start, two setInterval are executing.

Try this solution. idinterval is id function, kill to press start if !== false(initiale value) . Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/wu7spkw8/

```
var idinterval = false;
$("#reset").click(function () {
    //timer = new Countdown();
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
});

$("#trigger-start").click(function () {

    var check = true;
    if(idinterval !== false) {
        clearInterval(idinterval);
    }
    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 20 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    idinterval = initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

    alert(idinterval);

    $(".button-content-start").toggleClass("stop");
});

    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
        return timeinterval;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for comment :) see this second example:https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/jfLeb8b9/

Comment: thank you for your great support.

you are a big help :)

is it possible to start / stop and reset the countdown with just 1 button?

Answer (score 0):

Your scope is incorrect. Because you said `var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);`, the var is created in the scope of that method and then immediately expired because its the last line in the method. The next time you try to clear that interval the var is gone. You need to make it global or an attribute on a global object.

Comment: Thank you for your help,

but after setting the var for the whole function the countdown itself wont start anymore...

Comment: @NyanJoe Going back to your original code, try defining the var outside of the function and only referring to it (set/get) inside any functions. Or using top (last resort).